# JPA Collection has unwanted unique constraint in mapping table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

When I auto generate my database with `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create` an 'unwanted' unique constraint is being created in a mapping table.  I am running postgres 9.1, the create table statement becomes:

```
CREATE TABLE schemaname.scanalerts
(
  scanid bigint NOT NULL,
  alerts_id bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fkd65bd7541b5b1a8e FOREIGN KEY (scanid)
      REFERENCES rfid.scan (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fkd65bd754860b0886 FOREIGN KEY (alerts_id)
      REFERENCES rfid.alert (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT scanalerts_alerts_id_key UNIQUE (alerts_id ),
  CONSTRAINT scanalerts_scanid_alerts_id_key UNIQUE (scanid , alerts_id )
)
```

The unwanted constraint is `CONSTRAINT scanalerts_alerts_id_key UNIQUE (alerts_id )`, basically I only want the unique constraint on scanid and alerts_id.

I'm using JPA annotations to create the mapping, here is my code:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Alert.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "scanalerts", schema = RfidConstants.SCHEMA, 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "scanid"), 
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "scanid", "alerts_id" }))
private List<Alert> alerts;
```

Is there any way to stop the creation of the alert_id unique constraint?

Thanks

@JBNizet Here is the Alert mapping annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alert", schema = "schemaname", 
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"message", "alertPriority"}) )
public class Alert implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "alertSeq", sequenceName="ALERT_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "alertSeq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="versionnum")
    @Version
    private Long version;

    @Column(name = "message", nullable = false)
    private String message;

    @Column(name = "alertpriority", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AlertPriority alertPriority;
```

Comment: Please show us the code and the mapping of Alert.

Comment: @JBNizet  I have no mapping in the Alert class to the Scan class, should I have one there too?

Comment: No. But show us its code and mapping annotations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As said for example in [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html), `@ElementCollection` is used to map collection of basic types or embeddables. `Alert` is an entity and consequently
`List<Alert>` is not collection of Basic types or embeddables.

Because unique constraint that consists of `scanid` and `alert_id` is preferred, I assume that relationship between `Scan` and `Alert` does have many-to-many nature. That
can be achieved as follows:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "scanalerts",  schema = RfidConstants.SCHEMA,
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "scanid"),
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "alert_id")
)
private List<Alert> alerts;
```

Primary key of table contains both columns and that's why using `@UniqueConstraint` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks Mikko, that was exactly what I wanted.  Although to get the primary key creation on alert_id and scan_id I changed the List to a Set:  
`@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "scanalerts", schema = RfidConstants.SCHEMA)
@Column(name = "alerts_id")
private Set<Alert> alerts;`

Answer (score 0):

The constraint created is declared here:

```
uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "scanid", "alerts_id" }))
```

Just remove this and declare constraint inside `Alert` entity on each attribute.

Comment: `uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "scanid", "alerts_id" }))` this is the constraint that I want.  Without this constraint in the CollectionTable I still get the unique constraint placed upon alert_id.  I want to be able to re-use alerts for many scans, the constraint I need is that one a single scan must have unique alerts.  I'm not sure how I could add that relationship to the Alert.

Comment: sry i read too fast, what's the name of the entity declaring the collection ?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Although I was using `@OneToMany` instead of `@CollectionTable`, once I have changed `@OneToMany` to `@ManyToMany` the "unwanted" constraint hasn't been generated.